# $f(x)=g(x)\,$ on $\,(a,a+\delta)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ doesn't exist $\implies$ $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} g(x)$ doesn't exist$\;?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

In the proof of L'Hospital rule, we get at one point this equality:
$$\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \tag{1}$$
for a certain $x\in (a,b)$ and $c\in (a,x)$.

The hypothesis of the theorem (the version given everywhere) is that $\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists. By this hypothesis, and $(1)$, we get that $\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists (and is equal to the before mentioned quantity).

I am interested in the case where $\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ **doesn't exist**.

And am wondering if in this case, "$\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ doesn't exist" hold.

So I tried to take the contrapositive of:

$$\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \land \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} \notin \mathbb R 
 \implies \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \notin \mathbb R$$
where the equality on the left is true for $x,c\in (a, a+\delta)$.

The contrapositive is:
$$\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \in \mathbb R \implies \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} \in \mathbb R \lor \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} \ne \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $$

and there $\exists x,c \in (a, a+ \delta)$ for which the inequality on the right hold.

I think I understand why this contrapositive is true (by a similar argument than the one given below). Is the result true yet ? (I ask because I recall seeing somewhere that when the limit with the derivates doesn't exist we can have the limit $\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ existing).

---

PS: To speak frankly, I have to say that I also quite don't see why $(1)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} \in \mathbb R$ $\implies \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\in \mathbb R$.

I also took the contrapositive:

$$\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \notin \mathbb R \implies \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} \notin \mathbb R \lor \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} \ne \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $$

And what I have (figured out) is that, under the assumption that $\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \notin \mathbb R $, $\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} $ can exist but only under the condition that $\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} \ne \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, otherwise (if $\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} $ doesn't exist) $\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$ can be equal or not to  $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. Is my interpretation of the contrapositive right ?

Comment: For one of the questions in the body, as opposed to the question in the title: it's possible for $\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ to exist, even though $\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ does not exist.  One example: $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin(1/x)} {1/x} = 0$, but $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{- 1/x^2 \cos(1/x)} {-1/x^2}$ does not exist.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I am sorry, but after double thinking you're example doesn't fullfil l'Hospital conditions: $\lim 1/x = +\infty$ as $x$ tends to $0^+$ however, $\lim \sin(1/x) \ne +\infty$ as $x$ tends to $0^+$ (since $sin$ oscilates endlessly)

Comment: The statement of l'Hospital's rule says that *if* the limit of $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists and the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is of indeterminate form (and there are some technical restrictions on $g'$ not being 0) *then* the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ also exists and the two limits are equal.  It says nothing in the case that the limit of $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ does not exist.

Comment: Oh, right, then make that example that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{2/x + \sin(1/x)} {1/x} = 2$ but $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{-2/x^2 - 1/x^2 \cos(1/x)} {-1/x^2}$ does not exist.

Comment: The key to your question lies in the use of symbol $c$. The value $c$ depends on $x$ and should be represented more formally as $c_x$ or $c(x) $. If $f'(x) /g'(x) $ tends to a limit or to $\pm\infty$ then so does $f'(c_x) /g'(c_x) $, but it may happen that $f'(c_x) /g'(c_x) $ tends to a limit but $f'(x) /g'(x) $ doesn't. The situation should be compared with this : all subsequences of a convergent sequence are convergent, but a subsequence of a sequence may converge without the original sequence being convergent.